# count prime number in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

In Python 3, I am trying to write a function that counts the number of prime number in a list, can anyone help me with that?

```
def function(x):

  array = []
  aa = len(x)

  for num in x :
    if (num == 1 or num ==2):
      array.append()
    elif num >2:
      for i in range (2, aa):
        if (num % i )== 0:
          array.append()
        else:
          print (num)
          array.append(num)

  return len(array)

z = [4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
print (function(z))
```

but it shows an incorrect result!

Comment: I suggest you read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ for some tips to learn how to debug your own code. After you do that, edit your code in your question so that it is formatted exactly the same as in your .py file. Also show the results you get and tell us what you want it to be instead.

Comment: Please format your code and remove the `python-requests` tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my fix of your code.

```
def count_primes_in_list(numbers):
    primes = []

    for num in numbers:
        if num == 2:
            primes.append(num)
        else:
            is_prime = True
            for i in range(2, num):
                if num % i == 0:
                    is_prime = False
                    break

            if is_prime:
                print (num)
                primes.append(num)

    return len(primes)


z = [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
print (count_primes_in_list(z))
```

I'll note a few things for beginners to know.  Don't use reserved or type like words for methods and variables, name things descriptively.  Change `function` to `count_primes_in_list`, `array` to `primes`, `x` to `numbers` and so on.  Your test for a prime is incorrect.  A prime is a number greater than 1 that can not be divided by another number greater than 1 and less than its self.  In python don't put () around if tests.

Comment: Prime is greater than `1`, `1` is not prime. Note: `else:` clause on the `for` loop would also work instead of the `is_prime` flag.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is a little wrong and I'm not sure what you think `array.append()` is supposed to. And the `len(x)` is irrelevant. Note: `1` is not prime.

You can use the `else:` clause to the `for` loop, this means only execute if the for loop completes so if you `break` out early it does not get executed. So if the `num` is divisible by any number break `else:` add to `array`.

```
def function(x):
    array = []

    for num in x:
        if num <= 1:
            continue
        for i in range(2, num):
            if (num % i) == 0:
                break
        else:
            print(num)
            array.append(num)

    return len(array)

In []:
z = [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
print(function(z))

Out[]:
5
7
2
```

Note: there are many more efficient methods for checking primality but this is good enough for small numbers.

Comment: i am trying to add 1 in the list and it shows in the result , and its doesn't suppose to be

Comment: If you don't want 1 in the result just add a condition in the outer loop. Will update.

Answer (score 0):

```
def countPrime(num):
    d=0
    for n in num:
      if n>1:
         for i in range(2,n):
            if (n%i)==0:
                break
            else:
                d+=1

    return d
if __name__ == '__main__':
    num=[]
    cot=int(input())
    for i in range(cot):
        numbers.append(int(input()))
    
    print(countPrime(num))
```

Answer (score 0):

**prime number count in python list**

```
def countPrimeNumbers(numbers):
    count=0
    for num in numbers:
        if(num<2):
            continue
        else:
            for i in range(2,num):
                if(num%i==0):
                    break
            else:
                count+=1
    return count
```